# Order of IsHandleCreated and InvokeRequired

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I have the following code, and I've seen it written two different ways. I'm just curious which of the two ways is better practice:

```
if (this.IsDisposed) return;

if (this.IsHandleCreated)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}

log.Error("Control handle was not created, therefore associated action was not executed.");
```

vs.

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(action);
}
else    
{
    if (this.IsDisposed) return;

    if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
    {
         log.Error("Control handle was not created, therefore associated action was not executed.");
         return;
    } 

    action();
}
```

I'm mostly concerned with issues stemming from actions that require a control have a handle, and those were it's not explicitly necessary. If I were to do something like this, it seems to solve my problems by ensuring that the control will have a handle before the action is executed. Thoughts?

```
if (control.InvokeRequired)
{
     control.Invoke(action);
}
else
{
    if (control.IsDisposed) return;

    if (!control.IsHandleCreated)
    {
        // Force a handle to be created to prevent any issues.
        log.Debug("Forcing a new handle to be created before invoking action.");
        var handle = control.Handle;
    }

    action();
}
```

Comment: The first will block until the action is complete, the second won´t. Also, using BeginInvoke without calling EndInvoke is bad practice since possible Exceptions will get collected and are never released. Here´s a link on how to sync gui threads in winforms wihtout Begin / EndInvoke: http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2008/12/03/synchronization-in-winforms-with-lambdas.aspx

Comment: Whoops, that was a C&P artifact. It should read more like the first block, which is our code. The second is code I found in this article: http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2006/12/15/controltrifecta-invokerequired-ishandlecreated-and-isdisposed/

Comment: I am most concerned about exceptions that occur when a handle hasn't been created, but we try to perform actions on those GUI elements. Is it bad practice to force the handle to be created by assigning control.Handle to a variable?

Comment: I´m not sure what you mean with assigning the control Handle to a variable. Anyway, if you´ve that kind of problems then suppressing the error won´t solve it. If you simply "return" when the handle isn´t created then your program will almost certainly be in a invalid state.

Comment: @Mecaveli see my third code example. By doing it this way, I ensure that the handle is created before processing the action. This prevents the invalid state that could occur by simply returning. Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure about the Handle part tbh. I would go with Control.CreateControl as your method seems abit hacky :) See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrol.aspx

Answer (score 14):

You should always check both `IsDisposed` and `IsHandleCreated` before checking `InvokeRequired`. This is a maddening scenario that I've spent many hours mastering.

Here are the states that a control can be in:

- ***New***: the control exists, but his handle hasn't been created. In this case, `IsDisposed == false`, `IsHandleCreated == false`, but `InvokeRequired == false` **no matter what thread you use to call it**. If you trust the results of `InvokeRequired` without testing (or knowing some other way) whether the handle has been created and whether the control has been disposed, you could accidentally cause the handle to get created associated with the wrong thread, and it would crash your app. (**update**) This state really only applies if the control is (or is a child of) a form whose handle hasn't been created yet.
- ***Live***: the control exists, its handle is created. This is the easy scenario, nothing strange about it.
- ***Disposed***: this is similar to the "New" state above, but `IsDisposed == true`. Again, `InvokeRequired` will lie to you and cause you misery.

The right way to do this would be:

```
if(control.IsDisposed || (!control.IsHandleCreated && !control.FindForm().IsHandleCreated))
{
    // some exceptional condition:
    // handle in whatever way is appropriate for your app
    return;
}

if(control.InvokeRequired)
{
    control.Invoke(action);
}
else
{
    action();
}
```

**Additional Notes**

In .Net 2.0 (and 3.x) this sucked much more. `InvokeRequired` will now walk the control hierarchy to determine if any ancestor control's handle has been created, and validated which thread it was created on. However, if the control is on a form that has never been shown, the same dangers apply. Previously (in 2.0 - 3.5), `InvokeRequired` didn't walk the control hierarchy, leading to more opportunity for calamity.

Comment: So in this case, forcing a handle to be created could cause me more problems in the wrong run than anything? Or would it theoretically be created on the proper thread, considering it would have already been invoked when the handle would be created?

Comment: The control can't be displayed without a handle (that's the Win32 window handle, btw). However, that handle has an affinity to a thread. It's supposed to be associated with the UI thread. If you check `InvokeRequired` when `IsHandleCreated == false`, it will create the handle right then and there, **regardless of which thread you're on**. If you're on a background thread, it will associate the control's handle with that background thread, which will crash your app. So, again, check `IsHandleCreated` and `IsDisposed` before checking `InvokeRequired`.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand. Thank you for the explanation! In this case, if I check Disposed 1st, IsHandleCreated 2nd (And if the handle wasn't created, I create one), and then continue with the typical check of InvokeRequired etc. I should be golden.

Comment: NOOOOOO! Don't force handle creation! Don't call `Handle`! If you're on a background thread, it will create the handle **on the wrong thread** and it will **crash your app**! See the updated code sample above.

Comment: But from what I understand on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx I should check `InvokeRequired`, if it's false, check `IsHandleCreated`, and if need be, call `Handle`. Which goes directly against what you're saying, so I'm just hoping to get a clear answer. :)

Comment: From the article: "If the control's handle does not yet exist, InvokeRequired searches up the control's parent chain until it finds a control or form that does have a window handle. If no appropriate handle can be found, the InvokeRequired method returns false." They've apparently tightened this up in 4.0; however, it can still bite you if it's a form that hasn't been shown yet. Updated code sample.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference. The second might be very slightly more efficient, as it calls `IsHandleCreated` only when `InvokeRequired == false`.
`InvokeRequired` can only be `true` when the handle is created, so there is no need to call `IsHandleCreated` in this case.

Comment: Not true, wrong, and will cause pain and misery. Calling `InvokeRequired` when `IsHandleCreated == false` can cause Bad Things (tm).

Comment: @FMM care to explain? When the handle isn't created, `InvokeRequired` is `false` on all threads. So, if it's true, we now that the handle is created.

Comment: Yes, but if you call `InvokeRequired` from a background thread, it associates the handle with the background thread instead of the UI thread and crashes the app. Always check `IsHandleCreated` and `IsDisposed` before checking `InvokeRequired`. ALWAYS.

Comment: @FMM not true. `InvokeRequired` does not create a handle. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx